# Error when opening the Popularity Trends on a page in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-online

Below is the error i get when opening the popularity trends on a wiki page in SharePoint Online, the same page works fine in SP 2010, and after migration thru Sharegate this error i am getting, 
Is there any way to resolve or any feature to activate the same?

Sorry, something went wrong 
An unexpected error has occurred. 
Technical Details

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: 8847f09d-c004-3000-012f-b702edef115c

Thanks 
Paru

Comment: Maybe you can use this technique to get more Information about the error... https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69933/view-uls-logs-for-sharepoint-online

Comment: I am not allowed to run such scripts as of now.

Answer (score 0):

I got the resolution for the same, 
1. As popularity trends wasn't there in SP 2010, after migration though there is an option on the page (Default.aspx) it will not work
2. Also user has limited permission on the the page default.aspx and we cannot extend permission on this page as it coming from the root web.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f287a19b-3a59-42eb-a3e1-5cdd57b0a68d/how-to-assign-permissions-to-defaultaspx-in-teamsite?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy